# trouble with {base64 encoding of sha256 result} password generator

Tags: cryptography, base64

I'd like to encode a SHA-256 output (in hex) to give me a 16 character base64 string for password using purposes. base64 appears to not be what I would think it should be. Here's what I want.

```
(0)           "00000000000000000000000000000000" -> "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
(64)          "00000000000000000000000000000040" -> "AAAAAAAAAAAAAABA" 
(255)         "000000000000000000000000000000ff" -> "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAC/"
(2^16+16)    "0000000000000000000000000000100f" -> "AAAAAAAAAAAAAPAP"
```

heres what I get

```
base64encode("00000000000000000000000000000000")  
"MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAA"
```

This result is consistent with online converters, using R, etc.,
so obviously base64 is not what I think it is and I'm trying to do something else. If I'm not trying to "encode in base 64", what am I trying to do?

My favorite is:

```
> base64encode(64)
[1] "AAAAAAAAUEA="
> base64encode("64")
[1] "NjQA"
```

which just baffles me

Comment: Can you describe in words how you think the transformation should work? I agree, it isn't base64, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 works on byte arrays, so in your example, `base64encode("00000000000000000000000000000000")` is encoding the string value "000...", as a byte array. Since the byte value for the character "0" is 0x30, you're essentially encoding a byte array consisting of 32 `0x30` bytes (and by the looks of it, a null terminator (0x00) at the end).

If you're trying to get a 16 character output, you need to encode a 12 byte input (since Base64 produces 4 characters of output for 3 bytes of input), e.g. (You don't give the language, so I'm guessing at the syntax for byte arrays as `{ 0x.., 0x.., ... }`):

```
base64encode({0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00})
= "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

base64encode({0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01})
= "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB"

base64encode({0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40})
= "AAAAAAAAAAAAAABA"

etc...
```

The SHA-xxx algorithms should naturally produce a byte-array output, so you should be able to take the appropriate number of bytes from it, and pass them to `base64encode`. If your SHA method produces a hex string output, then you'll need to convert the hex string back to a byte array before passing Base64 encoding.